# Words in the alphabet of minimal generators of group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Let us suppose that $A=\{a,b,\ldots z\}$ is a minimal set of generators for a finite group $G$. Then, does the sequence $a,ab,abc,\ldots, abc\ldots z, abc\ldots za, abc\ldots zab,\ldots\}$ produce all the distinct elements of $G$. Note that the $z$ being in the end is just symbolic. It does not imply that there are just $26$ generators, rather it only implies that the group is finitely generated.

I think yes, but am not clear how to show that all the words in the sequence are actually distinct. What if two words get the same element of $G$? How about if $G$ is the symmetric group $S_n$ and $A$ is the set of transpositions $\{(12), (13),\ldots, (1 n)\}$. Can we ensure at least in this case? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Also, that’s really **bad** notation. It would be better to use an indexed set of generators.

Comment: It's not clear if you're asking whether all elements of $G$ appear, or whether all the elements in the sequence are distinct.

Comment: For an example where not all elements of $G$ appear, consider $G=C_n\times C_n$ and $A=\{a,b\}$ the canonical generating set. Then the sequence you wrote produces only $2n$ elements, instead of $n^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $n=|A|$ and $t$ is the order of the ordered product of the elements of $A$ (what you write $abc\cdots z$ but which, as noted in the comments, is bad notation, since it suggests there are $26$ elements),  then clearly the sequence has at most $tn$ different elements. So in the case of $S_n$ at the end of your question, we will not get all elements for $n\geq 4$ at least.

Comment: but sequences of longer length (with repeated elements ) are being taken as well

Comment: Let $x=abc\cdots z$ and let $W$ be the set $\{a,ab,abc,\ldots,x\}$. Note that this is a finite sequence, with $|W|\leq |A|$. Note that every element in the "long" sequence under consideration can be written in the form $x^iw$, for some $w\in W$. So the total number of elements in the sequence is bounded above by $|A|$ times the order of $x$.

Comment: Oh yeah my bad sorry.

Comment: yes, my question was was silly though!

Answer (score 2):

No, you don’t always get the full set of elements.

Take $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, written additively, and take as your minimal generating set $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,1)$. Your list of elements is:
$$(1,0,0), (1,1,0), (1,1,1), (0,1,1), (0,0,1), (0,0,0)$$
after which it repeats. So you never get $(1,0,1)$ or $(0,1,0)$.

Comment: oh makes sense,but then what could the intended thing we need to prove be.

Comment: @Onir: I don’t know what a true statement would be; what the OP wanted to be true just isn’t true, though.

Comment: Thanks, I at least thought it would be true for abelian groups, but your example shows otherwise.